# How to fix such an error in Django url-routing, get_object_or_404and Slug?

Tags: django, view, model, url-routing

How to get exactly the series that is specified in the URL, but the name of all series is the same, and they should be the same, but it takes only the URL of the series itself, that is, it searches only for the URL series, but not how, so that this series was in The series which is specified in the URL and also was in the season exactly the volume that is specified in the URL here is url

Url works fine but I can not go to the right series!

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', homeview, name='homeview'),
   url(r'^subscribe/$', validate_email, name='subscribe'),   # /series/
   url(r'^(?P<serial_slug>[\w-]+)/$', post_of_serial, name='post_of_serial'),  # /series/Prison_Break/
   url(r'^(?P<serial_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<season_slug>[\w-]+)/$', post_of_season, name='post_of_season'),  # /series/Prison_Break/season_5/
   url(r'^(?P<serial_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<season_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<series_slug>[\w-]+)/$', post_of_serie, name='post_of_serie'),  # /series/Prison_Break/season_5/2/  

]
```

Models

```
class Series(models.Model):
    id                                          = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    rus_name                                    = models.CharField(max_length=60) 
    eng_name                                    = models.CharField(max_length=60) 
    slug                                        = models.SlugField(unique=False) 
    serial_of_this_series                       = models.ForeignKey(Serial, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=True)
    season_of_this_series                       = models.ForeignKey(Season, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=True)
    number_of_series                            = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    description                                 = models.TextField(max_length=700, blank=True, default=None)
    size_of_torent_file                         = models.CharField(max_length=60, default=None)
    link_for_dowloand_serie_in_quality_360p     = models.CharField(max_length=60, default=None)      
    link_for_dowloand_serie_in_quality_720p     = models.CharField(max_length=60, default=None)      
    link_for_dowloand_serie_in_quality_1080p    = models.CharField(max_length=60, default=None)      
    rating                                      = models.FloatField(default=0, blank=True)  
    is_active                                   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp_rus                               = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated                                     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    timestamp_eng                               = models.CharField(max_length=60) 
    time_of_series                              = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=42)



    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('series:post_of_serie', kwargs=
                      {'serial_slug': self.serial_of_this_series.slug,
                       'season_slug': self.season_of_this_series.slug,
                       'series_slug': self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s | %s" % (self.rus_name, self.number_of_series)


    class Meta:
        ordering                                = ["-timestamp_rus"]
        verbose_name                            = 'Series'
        verbose_name_plural                     = 'Series'
```

views.py

```
def post_of_serie(request, serial_slug=None, season_slug=None, series_slug=None):
    serie                           = get_object_or_404(Series, serial_of_this_series=serial_slug, season_of_this_series=season_slug, slug=series_slug)
    #series_2                       = Series.objects.filter(serial_of_this_series=serial_slug, season_of_this_series=season_slug, slug=series_slug )
    context                         = {"serie":serie,}
    return render(request, 'series.html', context)
```

Error on the version above

> ```
> ValueError at /series/Colony/Season_1/episode_1/
>
> invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Colony'
> ```

There was also such an option but there comes an error from such that such a name already exists. In fact the fact that the name of the series and seasons should be the same!

```
def post_of_serie(request, serial_slug=None, season_slug=None, series_slug=None):
    serie                           = get_object_or_404(Series, slug=series_slug)
    context                         = {"serie":serie,}
    return render(request, 'series.html', context)
```

Comment: could you post the `Serial` and `Season` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try editing your views like this,

```
def post_of_serie(request, serial_slug=None, season_slug=None, series_slug=None):
    serie = get_object_or_404(Series, serial_of_this_series__slug=serial_slug, season_of_this_series__slug=season_slug, slug=series_slug)
    context = {"serie":serie,}
    return render(request, 'series.html', context)
```

The `serial_of_this_series` is a ForeignKey to another table, so when accessing the field, django automatically provides the primary_key of the corresponding table. By looking at your error, it seems that you haven't explicitly specified the `slug` field as primary_key, then the auto-incrementing integer field which is provided by the django automatically is trying to match with the slug you just provided. I'd recommend to access the corresponding field in the table, like `serial_of_this_series__slug`, ie, `slug` field(or whatever the field name is) in `Serial` table for query filterings.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm still a beginner, and unfortunately I did not think of it, thank you very much, I learned the lesson! If uvass has useful articles for Django, a rappa to see them, thanks again!